# What was the historical pronunciation of the digraph <gh> like?

Tags: pronunciation, historical-change, silent-letters, digraphs

What was the historical pronunciation of the digraph <gh>, as in *height, thought, thorough, laugh, enough, Edinburgh* like?

Answer (score 1):

From [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gh_(digraph)):

> - In the dominant dialects of modern English, ⟨gh⟩ is almost always either silent or pronounced /f/ (see ough). It is thought that before disappearing, the sound became partially or completely voiced to [ɣx] or [ɣ], which would explain the new spelling - ***Old English used a simple ⟨h⟩ - and the diphthongization of any preceding vowel.***
> - It is also occasionally pronounced [ə], such as in Edinburgh.

The follwing extract from [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Pronunciation-How-did-gh-at-the-end-of-some-words-become-an-eff-sound) makes some interesting  points:

> - English has a funny relation to its "gh" digraph.  It inherits it from the Germanic languages, where it's pronounced as a rasp in the back of the throat (the "voiceless velar fricative").  In modern German it's spelled with a "ch" as in "Bach".
> - It was pronounced that way in Old English and continued that way into Middle English.  Chaucer would have pronounced "knight" as the Germans pronounce it today, "knecht", with the "k" sounded.